# Returning header to STOMP client frame object after handshake

Tags: java, javascript, spring, websocket, stomp

Currently, when successfully connecting to an endpoint, I am passing a custom token (called access-token) back to the client via a response header.  This header is being set correctly and I can verify the header by analyzing the HTTP response.

However, when trying to get the header from the frame object the header is not set (see the JavaScript below):

```
 stompClient.connect(headers, 
                function(frame) {
                    console.log('=========================================');
                    console.log(frame.headers['access-token']);
                    console.log(frame);
                    console.log('=========================================');
                    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/test', function(stuff){
                       console.debug(stuff);
                    });
                },
                function(error) {
                    //error code
                }
        );
```

I am setting the response header as follows on the server:

```
public class HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptorImpl extends HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor {
@Override
public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request,
        ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
        Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {

        response.getHeaders().set("access-token", token);

         return super.beforeHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, attributes);
```

I stripped out some code and can confirm that the interceptor is being called.  I take it that this is not the correct way to pass a header value back to the client when the connect function is called?  I can't seem to find any documentation on how to accomplish this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ServerHttpResponse response - this is the response to a HTTP request, which you can inspect in more detail (by logging or in debug mode). Setting its headers will affect the HTTP response, not the STOMP stream which flows over the WebSocket connection. The STOMP headers of the CONNECTED are set by the message broker.

I do not know it for sure but I doubt that Spring is capable of inserting extra headers in the STOMP frames. (please correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement ChannelInterceptor and register it with output bound channel

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketServiceCustomHeaderInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketServiceCustomHeaderInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

        final StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        final StompCommand command = headerAccessor.getCommand();
        if (command != null && command == StompCommand.CONNECTED) {
            final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(command);
            accessor.setSessionId(headerAccessor.getSessionId());
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final MultiValueMap<String, String> nativeHeaders = (MultiValueMap<String, String>) headerAccessor
                    .getHeader(StompHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS);
            accessor.addNativeHeaders(nativeHeaders);

            // add custom headers
            try {
                accessor.addNativeHeader("HOSTNAME", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                logger.error("Error getting host name ", e);
            }

            final Message<?> newMessage = MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], accessor.getMessageHeaders());
            return newMessage;
        }
        return message;
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketBrokerConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public WebSocketServiceCustomHeaderInterceptor webSocketServiceCustomHeaderInterceptor() {
        return new WebSocketServiceCustomHeaderInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(webSocketServiceCustomHeaderInterceptor());
        registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(outboundPoolCoreSize).maxPoolSize(outboundPoolMaxSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible without a major hack. The issue is, the headers are completely rebuilt AFTER the ChannelInterceptors are called. See method `StompSubProtocolHandler.convertConnectAcktoStompConnected`

The method `StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageToClient` will also add a few headers depending on the type of message, for example by calling `afterStompSessionConnected` which sets the header "user-name" if the authentication is done.

I've tried adding headers as well but I'm about to give up... My guess is that the people who wrote the STOMP implementation in Spring wanted to strictly respect [the specifications](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Connecting)